# VB enumPrinters hangs

Tags: vb.net, network-printers

In the VB app I've just inherited from a colleague (now gone somewhere else), I have to solve a problem where the app just hangs and doesn't execute anything.

I've come to the conclusion that the problems lays here:

```
For Each printer In System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
```

which is called, in my source code, exactly like this:

```
    Protected Overridable Sub SetPrinter(ByRef data As IData, ByRef reportdoc As ReportDocument)
        Dim printer As String
        Dim paperorientation As String
        Dim papersource As String
        Dim papersize As String
        Dim devicename As String
        devicename = data.P_DeviceName
        If Not devicename Is Nothing AndAlso devicename.Trim <> "" Then
            paperorientation = reportdoc.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation
            papersize = reportdoc.PrintOptions.PaperSize
            papersource = reportdoc.PrintOptions.PaperSource
            devicename = devicename.Trim.ToUpper()
            For Each printer In System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
                If printer.ToUpper() = devicename Then
                    reportdoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printer
                    reportdoc.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CShort(paperorientation)
                    reportdoc.PrintOptions.PaperSource = CShort(papersource)
                    If CDbl(papersize) > 0 And CDbl(papersize) < 42 Then
                        reportdoc.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CShort(papersize)
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

I guess that it is getting stuck when interrogating Windows for the printers list.

For some reason, I'm not getting any answer from Windows about the printers (all network printers). Please note that this same code works just fine for thousands of times before failing. The only way I've found to reset is to reboot (restarting the app or the spooler isn't enough to make everything ok)

I haven't yet had the time to study the technology nor the code. What can I try next?

Comment: Since this function works based on the correlation between the flags, the level and the `PRINTER_INFO_X` struct you're passing, you need to post the function's definition and all the value you're passing when you make the actual call (what you posted is the *preparation*, to check whether the error is `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` (or the function returns `false`), then size the buffer and allocate the pointer to the structures) -- Note that this function is blocking and it may take a long time to return (depending on the flags/level and the type of structure used).

Comment: Does Windows itself list the printers without hanging when the VB app hangs?

Comment: How can I check that? apart from opening the "Printers and devices" GUI (that I'm going to do asap)?

Comment: @Jimi I have added the standard implementation of the function System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.
I don't know how I am supposed to know the values that I'm passing: I'm not passing any value when my program calls the standard code.

Comment: The code yo posted doesn't make sense:  `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` already runs something similar to the code you posted here (not the same, seems copied from the .Net Framework source code and modified), but that code is meant to only return the printers' names. Why would one run it again? I'd understand if you were to return a `PRINTER_INFO_2` structure and all the information that goes along with it, but why get the same information again?

Comment: Are you actually calling `EnumPrinters()` yourself, or you just posted what you think is the code that .Net runs under the hood when you read the `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` Property? Which, btw, you should assign to a local variable if you need to loop that collection. -- If you need to get information about the Printer, try to query the WMI's [Win32_Printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printer) class.

Comment: @AndrewMorton when the crash happens , the "Printers and devices" GUI opens smoothly.

Comment: What should happen if there is no match for the test `printer.ToUpper() = devicename`? You could create a boolean flag set to False, then in the loop you set it to True if the printer is found. After the loop, if the flag still has a value of False then the problem needs to be taken care of.